# store array from foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have function which is select data for specific user,then i want to  insert/create `'sid', pid,qtyremain, qtysold, amountpaid` into sales table.

but now when i run the query i get error below

> Array to string conversion

any one can help to correct where i did wrong

my form view blade

```
    <tbody id="tby">
    @foreach($search as $dt)

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="{{$dt->items->name}}" readonly="" class="form-control"><input type="hidden" value="{{$dt->items->id}}" name="pid[]"></td>
      <td><input  name="sprice[]" value="{{$dt->items->Sprice}}" readonly="" class="form-control sprice"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qtyload[]"  value="{{$dt->qty}}" readonly="" class="form-control qtyload"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qtyremain[]"   class="form-control qtyremain"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qtysold[]"   readonly="" class="form-control qtysold"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="amount[]"   readonly="" class="form-control amount"></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

my controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
  {

   //Start Store.
       request()->validate([
        'sid' => 'required',
        'qtyremain' => 'required',
        'amountpaid' => 'required',

         ]);
      for ($i = 1; $i < count($request->pid); $i++) 
          {
                $data[] =[
               'sid'=>$request->sid,
                'pid'=>$request->pid,
                'qtyremain'=>$request->qtyremain,
                'qtysold'=>$request->qtysold ,
                'amountpaid'=>$request->amountpaid,
                ];
    // dd($data);  
      }
                Sale::insert($data);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Successfully Stored');

        // }
     }
```

Comment: The error come from the validation.

Comment: how ? @TsaiKoga

Comment: plz post the form tag, or post the `$request->all();`

Comment: `sid , pid, qtyremain,qtysold, amountpaid`

`array:1 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "sid" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1"
    ]
    "pid" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "6"
      1 => "8"
      2 => "5"
    ]
    "qtyremain" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "2"
      1 => "2"
      2 => "2"
    ]
    "qtysold" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "18"
      1 => "38"
      2 => "53"
    ]
    "amountpaid" => "33333"
  ]
]`

Comment: The error message "Array to string conversion" comes from PHP itself. It's basically saying "I expected a string, but I received an array instead". You need to ensure that the data being POSTed, is a `string` and not an `array`. Looking at your markup (your HTML) you're using the array notation to name your fields. Remove the "[]" from each HTML <input> tag and try again.

Comment: @theruss, i got this error `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is an array. So you should iterate and make the insertion. So you can replace

```
Sale::insert($data);
```

with

```
foreach ($data as $record){
    Sale::insert($record);
}
```

Comment: where i can apply this sir?

Comment: edit but get this error

ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Comment: Can you add `dd($data)` AFTER `for` loop and check what's inside it?

Comment: `array:1 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "sid" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1"
    ]
    "pid" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "6"
      1 => "8"
      2 => "5"
    ]
    "qtyremain" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "2"
      1 => "2"
      2 => "2"
    ]
    "qtysold" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "18"
      1 => "38"
      2 => "53"
    ]
    "amountpaid" => "33333"
  ]
]`


this array data is correct but does not insert in to DB

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert multiple records. however, your request structure is like this:

```
[ 
  ["sid" => [ "1" ], 
   "pid" => ["6", "8", "5"], 
   "qtyremain" => ["2" , "2", "2"], 
   "qtysold" => ["18", "38", "53" ], 
   "amountpaid" => "33333" 
  ] 
]
```

And the error occurs because Laravel validation cannot check the field which value is array. If you want to check the array's element, you need to use `*`, do something like this:

```php
request()->validate([
    'sid.*' => 'required',
    'qtyremain.*' => 'required',
    'amountpaid' => 'required',
]);
```

However,
I suggest that you can use `sell[$i][pid]` instead of `pid[]` to the input name.

So you don't need to construct the structure by loop in backend.

```html
    <tbody id="tby">
    @foreach($search as $i => $dt)
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="{{$dt->items->name}}" readonly="" class="form-control"><input type="hidden" value="{{$dt->items->id}}" name="sale[$i][pid]"></td>
      <td><input  name="sale[$i][sprice]" value="{{$dt->items->Sprice}}" readonly="" class="form-control sprice"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sale[$i][qtyload]"  value="{{$dt->qty}}" readonly="" class="form-control qtyload"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sale[$i][qtyremain]"   class="form-control qtyremain"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sale[$i][qtysold]"   readonly="" class="form-control qtysold"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sale[$i][amount]"   readonly="" class="form-control amount"></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

So the request structure will be like this:

```php
["sale" =>[
  ["pid" => "1", "sid" => 2, "qtyremain" => 12, "qtysold" => 22, 'amountpaid' => 23.0],
  ["pid" => "2", "sid" => 2, "qtyremain" => 15, "qtysold" => 25, 'amountpaid' => 25.0]
  ...
]]
```

And **validate** the fields for this array and **insert** them in a faster and cleaner way:

```php
$data = request()->validate([
   'sale.*.sid' => 'required',
   'sale.*.qtyremain' => 'required',
   'amountpaid' => 'required',
   ...
]);

$sale = $data['sale'];
$array = collect($sale)->map(function($item) use ($data) { 
    $item['amountpaid'] = $data['amountpaid']; 
    return $item; 
})->all();
Sale::insert($array);
```

Comment: so we don't need to have that `for loop` ?, if yes when i run the code does not do anything even if i run `dd($data)`

Comment: @EmmaMfinanga That means the request cannot pass the validation. Check the `amountpaid`, I cannot found it in the html.

Comment: ` @endforeach
  </tbody>
     
    </table>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
     <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
       <tr>
        <th style="width:50%">Subtotal:</th>
        <td ><input type="text" name="sub_total"   class="form-control sub_total"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Amount paid</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="amountpaid"  class="form-control amountpaid"></td>
      </tr>
   
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

</form>`

`sid,amountpaid` is outside the `for loop`

Comment: ,, you can email me to see my code via TV/Zoom, if your interest to assist me  `emma4082@gmail.com`

Comment: @EmmaMfinanga then you need to validate without `*` because it is not array.  And add this value to the array.